# Why won't my collision detection in python work?

Tags: python, collision-detection, collision

I am currently trying to make a simple air hockey game for one of my classes. I am trying to make it so the goals do not make up the whole side of the screen, and are only a small portion of it. So when the puck hits a side of the screen that isn't the goal it will just bounce off and continue the game. but for some reason, the puck just goes through the side of the screen and the game does not reset.

The code:

```
 if(self.puckSquare.left < 0 and self.puckSquare.height > 143 and self.puckSquare.height < 310):
        self.gameLoop = False
        self.rightScore += 1
        print("Left Player " + str(self.leftScore) +  " Right Player" + str(self.rightScore))
    elif(self.puckSquare.left < 0 and self.puckSquare.height < 143 and self.puckSquare.height > 310):
        self.puckspeedX = -self.puckspeedX
```

Comment: Please post a [mre]. This little piece doesn't seem enough

Comment: What is ```self.puckSquare``` in this context?

Comment: @Liweinator `self.puckSquare` is the actual puck object

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your `elif` is wrong. You're checking if you're outside of both sides of the goal, which can never happen. You need an `or` rather than `and` for the `height` checks.

```
elif self.puckSquare.left < 0 and (self.puckSquare.height < 143 or self.puckSquare.height > 310):
```

Or you could leave the height checks out entirely, since you've already tested for the goal area in the earlier `if` check. You only need the `elif` to check that you're still hitting the wall.

```
elif self.puckSquare.left < 0:
```

Note: You don't need parentheses around the conditions in an `if` or `elif` statement. Some other languages do, but not Python.

Comment: When I do this it seems to make the whole wall solid instead of just a certain area

Comment: Ah, well, there may be more issues that prevent either of the checks working. I'm not sure I know enough about your data type to tell. Is `self.height` the right attribute to be checking (I'd expect that to be it's vertical width, not its position on the screen)?

Comment: I believe it is the height of the actual screen

Comment: Well, like I said, we don't know what library you're using (you haven't added one as a tag on the question), so I can't really help you with issues that are related to the API of the objects you may be using from it. You'd need to tell me what `height` means, and if it means what you imply it does, then the code should probably work!

Comment: Ok, I was able to work around the problem and make It work. Thank you for all the help!